# setState is not updating state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, reactive-programming

I have created a list in states, When I want to add a some thing to list, I check its length to show a button or not and it works but when I want to remove something from list, `if statement` doesn't work to remove button.

```
this.state = {
  allTasks: []
}
```

This is my `addToList` function :

```
addToList() {
    if (this.state.inputValue === '') {
      this.setState({ invalidInput: 'ورودی شما خالی است، لطفا چک کنید !' });
      return;
    }
    this.setState({
      allTasks: [...this.state.allTasks, this.state.inputValue],
      inputValue: ''
    });

    if (this.state.allTasks.length > 0) {
      document.getElementById('removeAllTasksButton').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('removeAllTasksButton').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

This is `removeFromList` function :

```
removeFromList(x) {
  this.setState({
    allTasks: this.state.allTasks.filter((e, i) => i !== x)
  });

  if (this.state.allTasks.length < 1) {
    document.getElementById('removeAllTasksButton').style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('removeAllTasksButton').style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

Comment: because setState is asyn, so you need to do the action in setState callback method, like this: `setState({}, () => {here put the if and else part})`.

Comment: @MayankShukla Thanks for response ...

Comment: working as expected with this change?

Comment: @MayankShukla Yes ...